# Docker Desktop WCF Service Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Tags: .net, sql-server, wcf, iis, docker-desktop

We have an image of our .NET WCF service on Docker Desktop Windows Container.

Using WCF Test Client to test one of the function in the WCF service to read from SQL Server database, it gets an error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.'

This is the Connection string:

```
<add name="myDatabase" connectionString="data source=myServer;initial catalog=myDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This is in the web.config:

```
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
```

How can I fix this error?

Unfortunately, my company doesn't allow using SQL Authentication in our application, we have to use Windows Authentication/Integrated Security.
The SQL Server database is not in the container, it's on our server.

The same WCF service works without the Docker with Anonymous Authentication is set to Enabled and Windows Authentication Disabled in IIS.

The Authentication is set to: Anonymous Authentication

Comment: The Docker container is not domain joined so you can't use AD integrated security (Windows Authentication). It's theoretically possible to domain-join a container, but it's a bit involved. Otherwise do `Integrated Security=false` and use a SQL Authentication login. Anonymous Authentication in IIS is only for IIS, not for SQL Server.

Comment: Well, do you actually connect to sql server by user name / password in management stuido? Do you even have sql server auth enabled?

Comment: In SSMS I use Windows Authentication to login, which is the same as integrated security

Comment: Yea, but that's useless for testing a non-AD login. You should login with sql auth, and if that works then transfer that to docker environment

Comment: Using SQL Authentication works, but unfortunately my company doesn't allow using SQL Authentication in our application, we have to use Windows Authentication/Integrated Security

Comment: The [mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) image is SQL Server for Linux running on top of Ubuntu Linux, so unless you can figure out how to join it to your Windows domain then you are not going to get Windows Authentication working with it.